# I can't install packages from the updater manager

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I can't install some packages through the software updater.
I get the following error message as shown in the attached image.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: You have dependency issues that should be resolved manually. Try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing --fix-broken`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If can't to solve with apt-get update -f, then try to upgrade system. Before you do this, make backup.

Comment: Milan: Please elaborate your answer and add more detail. Also make sure to correctly format commands as code. (See http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)